# Enabling Hyper-V on Windows 10 adds new detected displays that do not physically exist

Tags: hyper-v

I enabled Hyper-V on my HP Windows 10 Pro laptop today that has a 2nd monitor that is configured as an extended display (the laptop is #1, the external monitor is #2).  As soon as I restarted the computer, I noticed that my monitors were now duplicated (showing the same desktop on both monitors).

When I went into the "Display Settings" screen, I noticed that there were several additional identified displays (3,4,5,6) that do not physically exist.  I could no longer get back to my original display extended display configuration (#1 extended to #2), and could not get my physical monitors to be identified separately.

The "Multiple Displays" dropdown just showed various options for duplicating the screen across combinations of the 6 identified displays. Trying to manipulate the configuration seems to cause problems, and the system seemed to freeze for a little while, and then revert to the first duplicated configuration.

I tried just stopping the Hyper-v service, but that still didn't remove these "ghost" displays.

The only way that I got back to a properly configurable display detection was to completely disable Hyper-V.

So any ideas on what caused this?  Are there any Hyper-V settings that can fix this?

Comment: Same thing here :(. Did you find the answare?

Comment: Sorry Carlos.  I have not.  Back to using VMWare for now.  :(

Answer (score 11):

This guy has a [great tutorial](https://youtu.be/dYfeOnFZegI) that helped me fix this issue. It definitely has to do with the non PnP displays that show on the device manager.

Answer (score 6):

I recently experienced this same issue after installing Hyper-V on my MSI laptop (Intel HD Graphics 5600).

After updating the driver to version 20.19.15.5058 the issue did not go away.

I then opened Display Settings (right click on the desktop):

- Then I selected the monitor called "1|3"
- Scrolled down to "Multiple displays" and changed the setting to "Show only on 1"

I basically had to repeat the above step, continuously selecting the monitor named 1|x until it there were no more monitors called 1|x.

Once that was done I was able to choose monitor "1" and select Extend Display on 1 and 2.

The additional monitors remain in the list but appear inactive.

Comment: This but I had to do an additional step of "Duplicate on 1 and 2" essentially taking me back to where I started - it seemed not to work as the 15 second preview only had the screen visible on 2 - I clicked "OK" anyway and was back to the duplicate screens... then this time I could extend on 1 and 2 and it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is with **Intel(R) Graphics 4600** driver. Newer versions don't support Hyper-V so when you install them, Windows Device Manager will show several new non PnP Monitors.

The version that works with Hyper-V is **15.40**.

Revert to that version - `Intel® Graphics Driver for Windows® 10* [15.40][4th Gen]` - by downloading from https://downloadcenter.intel.com/. Make sure to download the zip file, because automatically installing from the exe might show you an error.

Comment: Thank you! I had that problem since started using wsl2. Beside additional screens I had a problem with jack audio and HDMI. Finally, everything is working properly.

Answer (score 3):

Try updating or rolling back the display driver. If the problem still persist, download the display driver provided by the PC manufacturer OR download an older version from the graphics card manufacturer. I solved mine by downloading the driver from Intel dating March 2016 (my laptop has Intel HD Graphics 4600).

Answer (score 2):

I updated my driver from the latest i could find in Intel's website (in my case win64_15407.4279), and the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

Driver Version 4835 also solved the Hyper-V related problem on my Lenovo with Windows 10 Pro Version 1709, OS Build 16299.125, also refer to https://communities.intel.com/thread/110642?start=105&tstart=0

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I discovered that Intel's update software was **not checking for graphics driver updates** when I ran the update tool because of this message I had never noticed:

> A customized computer manufacturer driver is installed on your computer. The Intel Driver & Support Assistant is not able to update the driver. Installing a generic Intel driver instead of the customized computer manufacturer driver may cause technical issues.

Updating manually to the *latest* driver (currently 20.19.15.5058, dated 2018-08-16) following the steps in the video in @yahyazini's answer worked for me (Asus N550JK, HD 4600 Graphics driver).

https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/97500/Graphics-for-4th-Generation-Intel-Processors